# Create a URL that pop up a new page showing data from SQL

Tags: php, sql

This is my database table:

[image: This is my database table]

I have made a PHP query the SQL database to HTML table:

[image: I have made a PHP query the SQL database to HTML table]

I wish to create a URL link in URL column that will call out data on every single row example like this picture:

[image: I wish to create a URL link in URL column that will call out data on every single row example like this picture]

Comment: Please add your code as text to the question.  Also some explanation of exactly what you need as text rather than images.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't store the URL in the database. That doesn't make sense. You can just create a profile.php where you send the user id via `GET`.

Your url would look like `"www.yoururl.com/profile.php?userid=2"`
Based on that parameter you would fetch the user data.

Your profile.php would look like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['userid']))
{
  $userid = $_GET['userid'];
}

//make your sql query with $userid | ... where id = $userid
```

Comment: sorry, i still not familiar with adding image in my question. i just done putting some image in. really thanks for your reply. hopefully someone can assist me to understand this function

Comment: @SiangMingFoo No Problem! Welcome to Stackoverflow, and I am happy that it helped you. If you need further information, do not hesitate to ask.